# Android Studio "override default fonts" leads to cut off Text ONLY in new Java Class Editor. Any way to solve this?

Tags: android

i need a really big font size in Android Studio and everything is working fine. Only 1 window is making trouble, which is the "new Java Class" window.
The text input fields are too small for the text. See Screenshot.
[image]Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to show this 'feature' to Google?

Comment: No, how would i go about this? The option says "not recommended" tho, so i guess they expect bugs. But there seem to be others who dont have this problem.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html

Comment: Android Studio has a bunch of bugs. To be honest, I'm afraid to update it until it's a few months because I do not want to fight with fresh "features" from Google